# How can I include details from the directory name in a gnuplot title?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

How can I include details from the directory name in the title of my gnuplot?  Currently, my gnuplot script is:

```
set multiplot title "Pressure Convergence Plots"
```

but I would like the title to say: 'Pressure Convergence Plots for overflow rate 1 and grid refinement 0', where 'Q1_GR0' is the directory name, and '1' and '0' are the numbers that follow 'Q' and 'GR' in the directory name.

If this is not possible, would it be possible for the title to say: 'Pressure Convergence Plots for Q1_GR0', where 'Q1_GR0' is the directory name?

I am using gnuplot version 4.6

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what version of sed you have but this works for me:

```
rep = sprintf("Pressure Convergence Plots for overflow rate \\1 and grid refinement \\2")
t = system(sprintf("sed -r 's/SF[0-9]+_Q([0-9]+)_GR([0-9]+)/%s/' <<<${PWD##*/}", rep))
set multiplot title t
```

The sed command captures the digits from after Q and GR and uses them in the replacement string. I've used `sprintf` to break up the command into two lines.

Comment: The full directory name is 'SF1_Q1_GR0'.  I didn't think the 'SF1' would interfere with the answer but, using your script, the title is: 'SF1_Pressure Convergence Plots for overflow rate 1 and grid refinement 0'.  How can I remove the 'SF1_' from the title?  Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the regular expression. It should do what you want now.

Comment: Or you could skip everything before the required tokens with `sed -r 's/.*Q([0-9]+)_GR([0-9]+)/%s/'`.

Comment: @Christoph or you could even remove more of the path from the input using something like `<<<${PWD##*_Q}`. The possibilities are endless! :)

Comment: Yes, this can be indeed endless. I just mentioned the `.*` because in my opinion its best to keep it rather generic, so that is also works for directories `RR15_Q1_GR2`. If that is desired is another thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a bash command. I like it very complicated:

```
rate = "`pwd | rev | cut -f 1 -d '/' | rev | cut -f 2 -d 'Q' | cut -f 1 -d '_'`"
refinement = "`pwd | rev | cut -f 1 -d '/' | rev | cut -f 2 -d 'R'`"
fulltitle = 'Pressure Convergence Plots for overflow rate '.rate.' and grid refinement '.refinement
set multiplot title fulltitle
```

Comment: Another variant could be: `info = system('pwd | sed ''s:.*/Q\([0-9]*\)_GR\([0-9]*\)$:\1 \2:'' '); set multiplot title 'Rate '.word(info, 1).' refinement '.word(info, 2)`.